# How can I get the android package name and close the app using adb shell command

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-tv

I'm trying to get the package name of an android app using adb commands. I've discovered this part:

`adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'"`, which gives me this:

[image: mCurrentFocus]

As far as I can understand, the package name is the one circled with red.

I've found somewhere the following code:

[image: Code1]

But when I try to run just the first line, without "package", it gives me this error:

[image: Error]

What seems to be the problem? How can I get the package name because i want to force-stop it programatically. Thanks!

Comment: Paste text instead of images and include the exact command you are running when receiving the error

Answer (score 0):

Using [AndroidViewClient/culebra:getTopActivityName()](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py#L1369) you can do something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

adbclient, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
pkg = re.sub('/.*$', '', adbclient.getTopActivityName())
adbclient.shell(f'am force-stop {pkg}')
```